# Sending logging information from Python code to C# GUI

Tags: c#, python, user-interface

I have a program that I am editing where the GUI is created in C# and then runs the process in Python.  Currently, Python is performing the following:

```
SetupLog()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.info()
```

to track events in the process.  Is there a way to send this information back to the C# GUI?

I am also trying to create a cancel button in the C# GUI that will kill the Python modules when exiting/canceling and was wondering if there was a better way than to do it based on the Process ID?

Answer (score 1):

It's *possible*, but this really isn't the best way to do things.

Unless that `SetupLog` function is disabling it, Python's default logging prints log messages to its stderr.

There are multiple ways to run a process in C#; if you're using, e.g., `System.Diagnostics.Process` to do it, you just need to set the `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError` property to true, then start the process, then read from its `StandardError` stream. In fact, if you look at the MSDN docs, there's [sample docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx) that does exactly what you want.

---

But the `logging` module is going to add log header information, which you'll have to parse out in your C# code, which is a waste. And of course, this means you can't use `logging` for anything else except communication with the parent.

If you're writing both the Python code and the C# code, it would be a lot cleaner to just use an explicit anonymous pipe (or socket, or named pipe, or …) and have both sides know they're talking to each other, instead of trying to trick them into doing so.